# Facebook API simple authorization failing javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following in my source code. I get the alert "No Response" and then the facebook page says 
"An error occurred with MYAPP. Please try again later"

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({appId: 'MYAPPID',status: true, cookie:true, xfbml: true});
</script>
<script>
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        if(!response.session){
        alert("NO RESPONSE");
        top.location.href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MYAPPID&redirect_uri=http://MYWEBSITE";
        }
    });
```

Can't see where/if I have gone wrong here.

Thanks

I am getting now the following error:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using older login code.  For FB.init, you should be setting `oauth: true` and you will want to check response.authResponse instead of response.session.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({ appId: 'MYAPPID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    if(!response.authResponse){
      alert("NO RESPONSE");
      top.location.href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MYAPPID&redirect_uri=http://MYWEBSITE";
    }
  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting a new error please see my post where I edited it.